# Why does a belief network need to be represented using a directed acyclic graph (DAG)?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, graphical-model

I would have thought that it was because DAGs preserve the dependency relationships between the variables, but I am currently unsure.

Answer (score 2):

A Belief (Bayesian) network is "defined" to be a DAG. A better question would be

> Why a *distribution* needs to be represented by a Belief network, i.e.
>   a DAG?

Dependency relationships can be modeled with both directed-acyclic and undirected-cyclic representations. Therefore, a distribution may be represented in either ways.

**Why acyclic and directed?**

Every distribution that can be sequentially factorized into conditional probabilities as follows can be represented by a DAG:

$P(X_1,...,X_n)=P(X_n|X_1,...,X_{n-1})\color{blue}{P(X_1,...,X_{n-1})}$,
$\color{blue}{P(X_1,...,X_{n-1})}=P(X_{n-1}|X_1,...,X_{n-2})P(X_1,...,X_{n-2})$,
...,
$P(X_1, X_2, X_3)=P(X_3|X_1, X_2)\color{brown}{P(X_1, X_2)}$,
$\color{brown}{P(X_1, X_2)}=P(X_2|X_1)P(X_1)$.

Belief network $G$ is built as follows: $X_n$ has no outlink, $X_{n-1}$ links to $X_n$, $X_{n-2}$ links to $X_{n-1}$ and $X_{n}$, and finally $X_1$ links to all $X_2$ to $X_n$.

Generally, there is no unique order for factorization, thus multiple networks can represent the same distribution. For example $P(A, B)$ can be factorized as $P(A|B)P(B)$ or $P(B|A)P(A)$ which are represented with two different Bayesian networks.

Every Bayesian network represents a sub-graph of $G$. Some directed links from $G$ are removed to introduce "independence assumptions between variables".

**How about cyclic and undirected?**

However, there is also Markov networks. Some distributions can be represented by Markov networks but not Bayesian networks [Example 3.6, Page 82, Probabilistic Graphical Models Principles and Techniques - Daphne Koller]. These networks use undirected lines to represent dependencies between random variables. A line between A and B represents [part of] a factor (a function).

For example, $\phi_1(A, B)=A.B/2=B.A/2$ is a factor from factorization $$P_{\theta}(A, B, C, D) = \frac{1}{Z(\theta)}\phi_1(A, B)\phi_2(B, C, D).$$ Note that we cannot unambiguously assign a direction to relation $(A, B)$, since both directions are justified for $\phi_1(A, B)$.

As an example for cyclic relations, factor $\phi(B, C, D) = B.(C+D)$ would be represented with a triangle among $B$, $C$, and $D$.

Generally speaking, cycles tend to complicate the learning and inference on Markov networks, so fewer cycles is favorable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we use DAGs to represent dependency relationships.

We need directed graph because condition probability P(A|B) is not same as P(B|A).

We assume it to be acyclic to get certain properties and ease calculations. You can create cyclic graph and you are going to get a lot of contradictions.

If you ease both the restriction(directed and acyclic), we get more general model called Markov Network.